# One to Many relation using non-primary field

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I'm looking into Loopback and stuck in finding a solution when two models (let's say `Customer`/`Orders`) have a one-to-many relationship but the primary key (`id`) of the parent isn't a foreign key in child table, but rather some non-key field.

For example, consider following two tables

```
Customer[ id(pk), name, social_security_number]

Order   [ id(pk), social_security_number(fk)]
```

I'm not able to create the relationship based on the above scenario. ***Loopback isn't returning orders when I query against a particular customer.*** Here is my actual code snippet (partial). **I'm using default id field as Primary Key**

```
{
  "name": "Customer",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "social_security_number": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {    
    "orders": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Order",
      "foreignKey": "social_security_number"
    }
  }
}

{
  "name": "Order",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "social_security_number": {
          "type": "number",
          "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "social_security_number"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: what is the stacktrace

Comment: Please, provide API query or query in code using model which as you say *Loopback isn't returning orders when I query against a particular customer*. Also a piece of data in both tables will be very useful to be sure that something really should be found.